# Javascript - MathJax - Disable certain expressions

Tags: javascript, mathjax

Is there anyway to disable certain keywords in MathJax?

I have these:

```
´undefined´
```

,

```
´2m in cm´
```

On both the "in" part will be replaced with some kind of ∈ value like "undef∈ed" and "2m ∈ cm", how can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
`text{undefined}`
```

and

```
`text{2m in cm}`
```

for these.  This is how you should be handling words in any case, since something like `` `word` `` is treated as w times o times r times d, and is rendered in math italic rather than a text font.